# Rockjam keyboard plays on its own

Tags: keyboard, repair

I have been using the RockJam RJ88DP keyboard for the past year, and I have been having a consistent problem with it. Most of the time, it works fine, but about once every few hours the lights start to flash and the keys play on their own. Specifically, every other D, A#, and F# play. In addition, even lightly touching any of those keys causes it to spaz out and play it many times per second. I have found that shaking the keyboard vigorously up and down usually fixes it temporarily, however I have tried everything and can't fix it now. Any suggestions?

Comment: This would be better addressed to the manufacturers, or a repair shop. Hardware fails are impossible to triage in text.

Comment: I agree this is a repair issue. Hopefully you are still under warranty. It sounds like some type of arpeggiator function is being inadvertently triggered.